# VPN (on OS X 10.4.11) - Behind two firewalls

Tags: vpn, firewall, mac-osx-server

How do I properly route VPN traffic past two firewalls?

- Network setup:  DSL Modem/Gateway/Router(FW1) >> Router(FW2) >> VPN Server
- Ports open on both routers/firewalls:

  - L2TP (UDP 500, 1701, 4500)
  - PPTP (TCP 1723)

FW1: 192.168.1.x
FW2: 192.168.2.x (VPN server is on this network)

Am I missing support for other protocols through the firewall (non-port related)?
If I DMZ FW2 from FW1, then user can connect. <-- Is this the only solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using double NAT causes problems with VPN and is bad practice in general.  I would remove FW2 or change it to bridge mode.  Either way, you need to eliminate the double NAT situation.

Comment: Apologies for the belated response. Double NAT was indeed the issue. Fixed now. Of course, the server died as soon as I got this figured out. Off to new challenges.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, should you start by checking /private/var/log/ppp/ on the client and /var/log/ppp/vpn.log on the server

Also the official documentation notices :
"*When configuring VPN,make sure the firewall allows VPN traffic on needed ports with the following settings:
Enable GRE, ESP, VPN L2TP (port 1701), and VPN ISAKMP/IKE (port 500).*"
(http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/NetworkSvcs_v10.6.pdf)

Might be related to those two protocols so:
[GRE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generic_Routing_Encapsulation)
[ESP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulating_Security_Payload#Encapsulating_Security_Payload)